# matching keys from dictionary and create lists with associated values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am new to python and I have a problem. Basically I have two dictionaries with depth as the key and the corresponding pH/H2 concentration as the values.

Now I want to create two new lists with pH and H2 values consisting of values taken from the two dictionaries. I only want to take values of pH and H2 when the depth in dictionary 1 equals depth1 + 6000 in  dictionary 2. So for example Depth 1 = 4000 then Depth 2 would be 4000+6000=10000 if this condition is met then the corresponding values of pH and H2 would be put in the new lists.

Since I am a rooky in python I have no clue where to start. I tried something like this:

```
   """Aligning of profile data"""
#fill in height of cathode for both profiles
Dept_H2 = 36000
Depth_pH = 42000
#calculate Depth difference
D_diff = Depth_pH - Depth_H2
print(D_diff)
#create dictionaries for pH and H2
H2_M = (Input2['concentration (mol/L)'].to_list())
Depth_H2 = (Input2['Depth H2'].to_list())
pH_dict = dict(zip(Average_depth, Average_pH))
H2_dict = dict(zip(Depth_H2, H2_M))
print(pH_dict)
print(H2_dict)

#create new lists for pH and H2 concentration values
pH = []
H2_con = []

for keys in pH_dict.keys():
    print(keys)
    for base in range(0, len(pH_dict[keys])):
        if keys in H2_dict == (pH_dict.keys() + D_diff):
            pH.append(pH_dict.values())
            H2_con.append(H2_dict.values())
```

When running this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File, line 42, in <module>
    for base in range(0, len(pH_dict[keys])):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

However even without this error I do not think this will work. Any hint on what I should be doing will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post the code where you read in Input2? Also, please give us a sample of the Input2 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pH = []
H2_con = []
for pH_depth, pH_val in pH_dict.items():
    possible_match = H2_dict.get(pH_depth + D_diff)
    if possible_match is not None:
        pH.append(pH_val)    
        H2_con.append(possible_match)
```

We traverse through the keys and values of the `pH_dict` and look for the desired match in `H2_dict` for each depth in `pH_dict`. The `.get` method of dictionaries treat the first argument as the key and returns the corresponding value if exists; otherwise, `None` (or the second argument if supplied) is returned. Then we check for existence and append.

If you have 3.8+, you can use `walrus` operator instead of seperately initializing and checking of `possible_match`:

```
...
for pH_depth, pH_val in pH_dict.items():
    if possible_match := H2_dict.get(pH_depth + D_diff):
        ...
```

You might also go for list-comprehensions but 2 lists make me not to :)